# Could not find control 'ControlName' in ControlParameter 'Parameter Name'

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I know that by the aforementioned topic, you might probably think it is a simple problem. But apparently, it isn't. Allow me to explain my requirement here.

I have a webforms ASP.NET application I am building with bootstrap. And there is this repeater control I built to display some data in which I attached a button in the item template for comments. And I want the button to launch a modal displaying a list of comments on that particular data item on the repeater and also have a provision for users to drop comments (something like facebook comments). Below is the markup for the bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        &times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                        Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptComments" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="float: left; width: 100%;" class="bg-info">
                                <b>'<%#GetUserInfo(Eval("UserId")) %>': </b>'<%# Eval("Comment") %>'
                                <br />
                                <div class="pull-right text-muted small">
                                    <em>'<%#GetTimeOfComment(Eval("DateCommented")) %>'</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both; line-height: 0px">
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    <cc1:PollCommentsDataSource ID="PollCommentsDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetByPollQuestionId" EnableTransaction="false">
                        <DeepLoadProperties Method="IncludeChildren" Recursive="false">
                        </DeepLoadProperties>
                        <Parameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="btnModal" Name="ModalPollQuestionId" />
                        </Parameters>
                    </cc1:PollCommentsDataSource>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I placed the above modal markup outside the repeater in which I have the button to trigger it. The reason is so the modal doesn't get hidden behind the modal background. But the problem is the datasource `PollCommentsDataSource`  that is supposed to populate the repeater within the modal isn't finding the button because it is within the main repeater. My question is how can I get it to see the button? Doing anything in code-behind isn't an option because I don't want the button click to take a trip to the server (it will be awkward for a modal launch)

P.S The button to launch the modal is a html button (`<button></button>`)

Thanks.

Comment: As much as I understood your situation, you want to pull the comments of particular item into the modal without round trip to server. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Imadoddin That's precisely the aim. Thanks for your response by the way. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How about adding hiddenfield in item template and assinging it comments? and getting that data while clicking button?

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin Are you talking about the item template of the main repeater or the comment repeater posted in the question? I'm sorry I don't quite follow your idea here. A little more explanation might do.

Comment: Can someone help me out please? Anybody? This is getting frustrating.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to follow my idea even if you have nothing in your mind

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. But I did it a in a much better way but it didn't work. I used a binded the data item to the value of the button but still I didn't get the button control to be seen by the datasource. This is what I did: `value='<%#Eval("Id") %>'`